# Why is my AnimatedContent not showing actual animation with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using `AnimatedContent` to animate between two different views but even though I'm specifying I want to use vertical transitions, it's still switching between the view but not applying the actual transition animation. Here's the code:

```
val isEditState = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

AnimatedContent(
     targetState = isEditState,
     transitionSpec = {
          (slideInVertically() with slideOutVertically()).using(SizeTransform(clip = false))
     }
) { targetState ->
     if (targetState.value) {
          EditView(...)
     } else {
          NonEditView(...)
     }
}
```

How can I fix this so the animation works?

If I use `AnimatedVisibility` it does work but I have to apply it to each view specifically.

```
AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = isEditState.value,
        enter = slideInVertically(),
        exit = slideOutVertically(),
        content = EditView(...)
    )
```

Comment: What happens if you just use the default `transitionSpec`? Is it still broken? Also, is it possible to replace `targetState.value` with just `targetState`? They make a big deal in the docs about using the lambda value as-is:

"Note that you should always use the lambda parameter and reflect it to the content. The API uses this value as the key to identify the content that's currently shown."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `isEditable.value` as the target state:

```
AnimatedContent(
     targetState = isEditState.value,
     transitionSpec = {
          (slideInVertically() with slideOutVertically()).using(SizeTransform(clip = false))
     }
) { targetState ->
     if (targetState) {
          EditView(...)
     } else {
          NonEditView(...)
     }
}
```

The variable `isEditable` (which is a State) doesn't change, that's why it doesn't animate. What changes is its value.

Comment: Looks like you are referring to `isEditable.value` but then use (correctly) `isEditState.value`.

Comment: Also, is part of the original issue that she is using

`val isEditState = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }` rather than `val isEditState by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }`. Seems like the other problems stem from that.

Comment: This helps me thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think your error is actually in using

```
val isEditState = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
```

rather than

```
val isEditState by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
```

If you update that to match the standard usage of `remember`, I think the rest of the solution will fall into place:

```
val isEditState by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

AnimatedContent(
     targetState = isEditState,
     transitionSpec = {
          (slideInVertically() with slideOutVertically()).using(SizeTransform(clip = false))
     }
) { targetState ->
     if (targetState) {
          EditView(...)
     } else {
          NonEditView(...)
     }
}
```